# When can you call a bound service in the Android Activity lifecycle?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-service

I am quite new to Android dev and struggling with with the concept of bound services

I have bound a service to an Activity in the `onCreate` method of the activity

```
startService(intent);
bindService(intent, mConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
```

`mConnection` is a `ServiceConnection` object for which I have overridden the `onServiceConnected` callback method in an anonymous class

In the callback, `mService` (which is a class member of type `LibraryService`, `LibraryService` is my subclass of `Service`) is set to reference the `LibraryService` object we are binding to:

```
mService = binder.getService();
```

I thought that after the call to bindService in onCreate I would then be able to call the LibraryService through mService reference, but it is still set to null at this point indicating that the onServiceConnected callback has not been executed.

I have tried to print the value of a string generated by an `mService` method using Log:

```
if (mService != null) {
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "In onCreate getLogFileName string value: " + mService.getLogFileName("pulse"));             
} else {
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "In onCreate getLogFileName string value: null");                
}
```

as I mentioned - it was still null in onCreate, I then added the same log code to onStart and onResume but mService is still null

My question is when does that callback get executed? I would have thought it would have to occur within the body of the `onCreate` method but clearly not. I think I need a few pointers in how/when callbacks are executed by the Android system

I know the callback does get executed as I have put a breakpoint on the statement where mService is instantiated and it hits that statement. I just don't understand when its occuring, i.e. how do I know when its OK to assume `mService` has been set? Can I only access it within the body of the `OnServiceConnected` callback?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Service binding is asynchronus and, as such, you have to handle this with a little of synchronization.
Hence, after calling bind service you could do something like

```
synchronized(this){
   while(mBoundInstance == null)
      this.wait();
}
```

in onServiceConnected:

```
synchronized(this){
   this.notify(); //wakes up thread: now mBoundInstance is 100% != null
}
```

Note that is good putting that wait in an asyncTask, so that ui does not get frozen.

Comment: this looks like something pretty fundamental I should understand - is this a java wide thing or android specific (I'm thinking of what to googleto fid a few introductory tutorials)

Comment: This is plain java: you could look directly at java's official tutorial, concurrency section. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/sync.html

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at https://stuff.mit.edu/afs/sipb/project/android/docs/guide/components/bound-services.html

There it says:

- you only need to interact with the service while your activity is visible, you should bind during onStart() and unbind during onStop().
- If you want your activity to receive responses even while it is stopped in the background, then you can bind during onCreate() and unbind during onDestroy(). Beware that this implies that your activity needs to use the service the entire time it's running (even in the background), so if the service is in another process, then you increase the weight of the process and it becomes more likely that the system will kill it.
- You should usually not bind and unbind during your activity's onResume() and onPause()

Answer (score 0):

Now that I re-read your question and description I think you wanted something else to know.
I don't delete the first answer as it it generally the right answer if only reading the header of the question.

Usually you want to really build your UI in/after onResume. Or you would start a thread that polls your service periodically - and start that thread onResume (and stop it onPause). You can move that "init" code to a special init() method.

onStart you call bindService
onResume you check if mService is not null then you start the init() method (it is not null if you just put your activity in background shortly then it will not go over onStop but only call onPause and onResume).

Also you call init() from your ServiceConnection anonymous class right after you assigned the mService from the binder object.

Remember to always null the mService in ServiceConnectionon.ServiceDisconnected and also after you called unbindService() in onStop().
Also remember: you cannot re-use the ServiceConnection object after one bind(and unbind) has been done. It will give an exception. So just do a new ServiceConnection on every new bind (every cycle of onStart/onStop).